# Cannot run docker as non sudo user

Tags: linux, docker, user-groups

cannot run docker as non-privileged user. I added user to docker group with:

```
sudo groupadd -a -G docker $USER
```

I loggeg out and in again, still no success.
I am running docker on a Ubuntu 21.10 system.

Comment: Please provide the output of `id` to check whether that actually worked. Also please provide the entire error message you get when trying to run `docker run --rm -it hello-world`.

Comment: It worked now after I turn off and on my laptop again...Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

When you use "sudo" you are forking a new process as "root". So the $USER variable will be "root" and not your user.

Replace the $USER by the name of the user you are trying to add privileges.

**sudo groupadd -a -G docker username_here**

Finally, logout and login again, start a new terminal session and run "**id**" to check if the user now belongs to the docker group.

Comment: No, that’s not the cause. At the time the `sudo` process is started, the variable `$USER`, which is shell-specific, has already been replaced with its value. It’s certainly true that the environment variables change, but `groupadd` does not use these.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Daniel. I felt this was not right in the minute that I finished writing it hahah